# How do I crop Fixed Patches around the red dots in an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and I am not even sure how to tackle this problem. I have this image of 500x500 pixel with red dots and white lines in it.

[image]

Considering each red dot as center and could I draw a fixed bounding box of 25X25 size around the red dot? I need to identify every red dot in the image.

[image]

Note: condition is that I need to find a bounding box of fixed size (25x25) and the red dot must be in the center of the bounding box.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, using [`numpy` slicing](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/index-and-slice/) to get the red channel, [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create a mask of the red dots and [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) to get the *bounding rectangles* of the dots. We can use this info to draw the new `25 x 25` rectangles:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "C://opencvImages//"
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath + "oHk9s.png")

# Deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Slice the Red channel from the image:
r = inputImage[:, :, 2]
# Convert type to unsigned integer (8 bit):
r = np.where(r == 237, 255, 0).astype("uint8")

# Extract blobs (the red dots are all the white pixels in this mask):
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(r, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Store bounding rectangles here:
boundingRectangles = []

# Loop through the blobs and draw a 25 x 25 green rectangle around them:
for c in contours:
    # Get dot bounding box:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Set new bounding box dimensions:
    boxWidth = 25
    boxHeight = 25
    # Center rectangle around blob:
    boxX = int(x + 0.5 * (w - boxWidth))
    boxY = int(y + 0.5 * (h - boxHeight))

    # Store data:
    boundingRectangles.append((boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight))

    # Draw and show new bounding rectangles
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(inputImageCopy, (boxX, boxY), (boxX + boxWidth, boxY + boxHeight), color, 2)
    cv2.imshow("Boxes", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Additionally, I've stored the top left coordinate, width and height of the rectangles in the `boundingRectangles` list. This is the output:

[image]

Comment: consider calculating `int(x + w/2 - 0.5 * boxWidth)` etc to center the boxes on the centers of the blobs

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Nice. Thanks for the suggestion! I modified the code to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use an HSV mask to mask out everything in your image except for the red pixels:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_box(img, cnt):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    half_w = w // 2
    half_h = h // 2
    x1 = x + half_h - 12
    x2 = x + half_h + 13
    y1 = y + half_w - 12
    y2 = y + half_w + 13
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0))

img = cv2.imread("red_dots.png")

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
ranges = np.array([[100, 0, 0], [179, 255, 255]])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, *ranges)
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_masked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    draw_box(img, cnt)
    
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Notice at this part of the `draw_box()` function:

```
    x1 = x + half_h - 12
    x2 = x + half_h + 13
    y1 = y + half_w - 12
    y2 = y + half_w + 13
```

Ideally, instead of `- 12` and `+ 13`, it should be `- 12.5` and `+ 12.5`, but there cannot be half pixels in OpenCV, or an error would be thrown.